# configuring parsing for chartJS for multiple datasets

Tags: javascript, chart.js, visualization

I'm trying to use chartJS to draw multiple lines on a graph for each of my datasets. The data comes in as a specific format, and I can't seem to work out the syntax to get chart to map the data values properly to their axes in order to draw the graph. Here's what my data looks like:

```
const allData = [{
  "data": {
    
    "shortUrl": "http://[DOMAIN]/[URL1]",
    "clicksByDate": [
      {
        "date": "3/21",
        "count": 1,
      },
      {
        "date": "3/22",
        "count": 3,
      },
      {
        "date": "3/23",
        "count": 2,
      }
    ]
  },
  { ... }
}]
```

In this format, I want to graph each `shortUrl` as a separate line, where the X axis represents the `date` that clicks occurred for the URL, and the Y axis represents the `count` of clicks on that date.

The closest I could get to understanding this was:

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("stat-chart"), {
  type: "line",
  options: {
    
    parsing: {
      xAxisKey: "clicksByDate.date",
      yAxisKey: "clicksByDate.count",
    },
  },
  data: {
    labels: allData[0].data.clicksByDate.map((row) => row.date), //know this is wrong, but not sure how to make sure all dates from both sets are represented
    datasets: allData,
  },
});
```

but it just draws the axis and doesn't map the data. No errors are thrown.

I added [a codepen here](https://codepen.io/heaversm/pen/bGxXQwB?editors=1111).

Comment: I am not sure I understand how you want your plot to look... if you want the data for each url to be represented by a line, than the `shortUrl` should be the `label` of that line, and `clicksByDate` would be the actual line `data`. I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1qrm2x8/) with that mapping, but I suspect it's not exactly what you wanted. Please let me know.

Comment: Yes - I think this is right in terms of getting the axes labeled properly, but no data outputs - the only way I've found to do that is actually manipulate the data itself to output a simple array of values per dataset, which I'm trying to avoid. Maybe that's not possible with this library? My understanding was that the "parsing" could allow you to specify which object key would pertain to the data you wanted to plot (in this case, Y being the "count" values, X being the date they occurred on.

Comment: The `parsing` property is helpful in structuring complex data, but in your example it was not used as it is meant to - the values of `xAxisKey` and `yAxisKey` should indicate the path *inside each object* of `data.datasets[i].data` array. The paths `"clicksByDate.date"` and `"clicksByDate.count"` expected the data to be structured like `{datasets: [{data: [{clicksByDate:{date:"3/20", count: 10}]}]}]}` i.e., `clickByDate` was expected to appear in each datapoint, while in your example it was an array, at the position where `data` was expected - actually it found no `data` so it plotted nothing